# Projection on the hyperplane H: $∑x_i=k$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, projection

Consider the hyperplane $H$: $∑x_{i}=k$, where k is a constant and $i=1...n$. How do we project a vector onto this subspace? More precisely, how do we compute the projection matrix $P$?

Comment: See related question and answer in here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2320236/projection-on-the-hyperplane-h-sum-x-i-0?rq=1

Comment: Thank you! I did take a look at it. As I'm vastly inexperienced in this field, I'm having trouble accounting for the constant k in the rhs, in my calculation. Maybe you could help me with a hint?

Comment: Try and draw it in 2 dimension to understand the connection between the different projections to the hyperplanes when the constant is either $k$ or $0$.